# How to use The Graph (GRT) with Quorum to index events and serve them via GraphQL?

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, the-graph, subgraph

I saw a few videos of using a graph node to index blockchain events, and serve them via graphql, which seemed very useful. The common pattern in these videos that I observed:

1. They are using Infura/Alchemy link for their node
2. They are using the Graph Studio to deploy their subgraph to a public blockchain

Now, we use Consensys Quorum deployed on our own private infrasturcture. We get a http URL (much like Infura links) to which we connect via web3js. However, we cannot use Graph Studio as it wont be able to connect to our private network.

Hence, I am guessing a lot of manual configuration is needed to use subgraphs here? Can someone help me understand, atleast on a high level, what are the steps I need to do here ?

Answer (score 0):

apologies this answer is probably a bit late.

I'm not sure about using the graph to index private chains but assuming you are trying to achieve indexing using the graph, you could use a tool like [envio](https://envio.dev). It's also a framework for indexing smart contract events but it allows you to pass an rpc endpoint in your config to connect to any evm chain.

(disclaimer, I am a dev at Envio)